# Close the current tab(which was not opened by script) of a browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

Basically what I am trying to do is prevent user from opening my website in multiple tabs on a single browser.
so if the user duplicates the tab or manually pastes the URL in another tab then it should show some error message and then close the new duplicated tab.

Comment: You can't, tabs/windows can be closed programmatically only when they originally were opened by a script.

Comment: What have you tried?  It's always good to accompany your question with what you have experimented with, rather than make it feel like you want someone else to do all the work for you.

Comment: i have tried doing window.open('', '_self').close() or directly window.close()
but as @Teemu pointed out, it shows error that you can only close the window which was opened by the script.

Comment: There are [*many questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+close+window) about this already.